# Accidentally started diskpart format on 2TB external drive, and now Explorer can't see it

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

On the command line, I used `format override fs=fat32` while in `diskpart`, assuming I had selected my 8GB flash drive, and realised I'd accidentally selected my 2TB external drive which had been assigned the same number after reboot (it's been a long night).

The format ran for about a minute or so, without progressing to 1%, before I realised what I'd done and did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

The external drive no longer shows up in My Computer, even after a reboot of my computer, although it is visible in Device Manager.

As you can imagine, I'm panicking a fair bit right now, fearing I've lost a terabyte and a half of data - no backups of this particular drive, *obviously*.

Any help - and assurance that I haven't lost anything or wrecked my drive - would be vastly appreciated. Thanks.

---

**Update 1:** *In `diskpart`, doing `list volume`, selecting the raw volume with `select volume #`, and then doing `assign` assigns it a drive letter, making it discoverable to Explorer and in My Computer, although it then gives  the error that it needs to be formatted. From thereon, clicking on the drive in My Computer returns the error:*

> H:\ is not accessible
>
> The parameter is incorrect.

---

**Update 2:** *Running the trial ("Simple") version of GetDataBack on the drive took around 26 hours, and returned at least a hundred different sectors of varying sizes, including large FAT32 and NTFS sectors.*

---

**Update 3:**

*Doing some detailed digging into the results of GetDataBack's thorough search showed me [the full list of filesystems](https://pastebin.com/6QCSnySV). Shockingly, buried in that list I found a 1.82 TB sector, which roughly corresponds to the size of my lost data. It's likely that this is it, and that all I now need to do is to recover to it to get 99% of my files back, but I'm hesitant to do anything before I understand what the other file systems are and why they're so large. The Ext filesystem registers as over 500GB, for example, and several other NTFS filesystems are over 400GB. **Does anyone have any idea what these other file systems may be?***

Comment: Wait wait wait... Windows 7 cannot format a 2TB volume as FAT32, it simply won't do it because the volume is too large (Windows' max is 32 GB for FAT32). I reckon all that happened is that the "override" argument forced the volume to dismount.  So you lost the drive letter, no big problem, you can go back into diskpart and "list volume", select the volume without a drive letter and then "assign letter=x" to get it back.  Good luck!!

Comment: Damn, you got my hopes up. I tried doing that, and it came back successful, but then I got this: http://imgur.com/a/ZAAx5.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/4w3Gk It's now at least showing up in My Computer, but clicking on it comes back with the format dialogue seen above.

Comment: Scratch that, it now results in a complete dead end: http://imgur.com/a/xvpMd.

Comment: Bah, that's so weird.  I'm wondering if diskpart has a bug whereby it ignored your "fat32" argument and went ahead with an ntfs format.

Comment: Um, in diskpart, did you issue a "clean" command before doing the format command?

Comment: I might have, but I'm honestly not entirely sure. I was trying to perform a clean before the format, but whether I issued the clean to the external HDD or the intended USB drive it's hard to be certain of. It's entirely possible I just formatted it.

Comment: Yeah there we go I would bet the CLEAN command you actioned was against the hard drive too.  CLEAN does this: *Removes any and all partition or volume formatting from the disk with focus. On master boot record (MBR) disks, only the MBR partitioning information and hidden sector information are overwritten.*  I think it's time you started looking at recovery tools to get your data back.

Comment: Okay, so far I've used the demo version of GetDataBack. After running on the highest setting for about 26 hours, this is what's come back: http://imgur.com/a/c0vRQ. There are at least 100 different file systems, with large sizes of both NTFS and FAT32 file systems. I'm not sure which of these to select, or what exactly it means, and the manual PDF for GDB is outdated. Does this mean it's likely that I've lost a lot of data? Also, if I select one of these file systems, can I come back to recover files from the rest of them, or do I have to choose a single file system to go with from hereon?

Comment: TestDrive is currently most of the way through running, but if GetDataBack is showing so many possible file systems of varying sizes then I'm guessing there's very little TestDrive can do?

Answer (score 0):

So you potentially have a disk that is partly NSTF and partly FAT32. What you would want to do is trick the PC into reading it as NSTF even though it partly FAT32 now.

Have you tried a tool like Piriform's Recuva?

Comment: I see EaseUS has a tool claiming to help in a situation like this as well. You may need to remove the disk and plug it into a USB Hard Drive dock to get it recognized.

Comment: The HDD is plugged out and sitting quiet for now, it was making some odd boot noises and I feel like the longer it's on the more likely it is to get worse. I haven't tried any recovery tools yet because I'm banking on the possibility it won't be needed and that a more simple, less painstaking solution is still on the table, especially given how little time the format was running for.

Comment: I read something online that if a drive simply isn't showing up in My Computer, but is visible in Device Manager and in diskpart itself, it simply needs a drive letter assigned to it to be recognised by My Computer again. Could it be that simple? Would using diskpart's `assign` command work?

Comment: Any idea the type of Master File Table it had and if it can be recreated? It seems like that may be the only thing affected.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by type? And how would I go about recreating one if I did know?

Comment: @Hashim Well the Disk probably has a GUID table or an MBR table and maybe that is all that is damaged and the files are ok.A quick internet search points to tools to fix these tables.

Answer (score 0):

I can appreciate all the help you are receiving here. But, if you started formatting the partition then you probably immediately overwrote the master file table. The file table is what tell Windows where each piece of every file on the physical drive is located and which files and folders exist. Kind of like a card catalog at the library.

Without that, there is no simple way to get your files back. You'll have to use a data recovery tool to try to look for the files manually. The tool you said you used sounds like it is trying to restore a deleted partition. That is the wrong kind of scan. You don't have a deleted partition and you can't "restore" the drive to normal operation.

Your only option at this point is to manually scan for any files and see if they can be recovered. A tool like Recuva (as suggested earlier) has given me good success. I've also used File Scavenger with great success. It will identify the files it can find and tell you if they are recoverable or not.

Unlike a library with a missing card catalog, your "books" aren't all in one piece if the drive is fragmented. This means there is a large possibility only smaller, non-fragmented files can be recovered. There is some plus to this, because most of absolutely non-replaceable data is small in size (pictures, word documents, etc.)

What hasn't been mentioned is that if you write anything to the drive you are damaging your chances of recovery. Professionals clone the drive first so they don't mess with the original. You have to be absolutely sure you are not writing anything back to the drive. All files restored need to be restored to a different drive, and NEVER EVER use any tool to "repair" a drive if it is your only copy of the data.

You also mentioned noises and concerns about making things worse by letting the drive run. This is a totally separate issue. Your drive isn't going bad because you formatted it or leave it plugged in. If it has other physical problems, then you've just compounded the difficulty of this recovery exponentially.

Also, if this data is really, really important to you then you should definitely NOT be attempting any data recovery on it. Send it to a professional.

I don't want to sound like I'm saying told you so, but I hope this is a lesson learned, and a lesson for all other readers - BACKUP YOUR DATA. It's unbelievable how many people have critical, can't possibly lose it, it's the end of my life as I know it data, but don't back it up.

Best of luck to you.

Comment: If the tool you're referring to is GetDataBack, it is indeed a data recovery tool. When researching the best one to use, it came back more highly recommended than Recuva, which is why I started using it. Good shout on the noises, it isn't physically damaged so it should be okay in that sense. You're right that I probably should have cloned the drive and worked on the cloned image, but GetDataBack claims to be a read-only tool, so it should be fine in that sense. There are three steps to GDB: scanning the drive, selecting file system fragments/sectors as indicated...

Comment: ...in [this image](http://imgur.com/a/c0vRQ), and recovering files from within those file system fragments. I'm just unsure on the specifics of how exactly the second step works, and was hoping someone here could enlighten me - specifically on whether I'm limited to selecting one file system fragment and copying the data from that alone, or whether I can keep coming back to Step 2 to copy files from each file system sector.

Comment: From what you say about this not being a problem of lost partition tables, as @tekFranz believes it is, I assume that [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) would be unsuitable in this instance?

Comment: From my description of GetDataBack above, does Recuva function in a similar way, or is it simpler to use?

Comment: What I'm really confused about GDB is why it brings back significant portions of several different file systems. How is it possible for a single drive to contain large FAT32, NTFS and exFat partitions?

Comment: I'm not suggesting GetDataBack isn't a good tool. I haven't used it before. If it says it is read-only then what you said makes sense and the process sounds right. These tools scan the raw data on a drive and try to identify the original structure. The problem is there is a lot of raw data that looks like structures it is looking for. You also started re-formatting it as FAT32. It likely is seeing that also. The bad news is it probably isn't detecting the sections right unless it identified a single 2TB NTFS section you can select.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GetDataBack. Formatting a drive doesn't remove a partition. So, you need to scan the existing partition, not the entire raw hard drive. Depending on the software, sometimes this is an option. We really don't care about identify structures, because they likely don't exist. What we need to do is scan the raw partition and find files. But, if one of these tools could identify the actual original file table and structures you'd be certain of a good data recovery.

Comment: Okay, so I've been digging into GetDataBack, and managed to grab an entire list of all the filesystems that it returned: https://pastebin.com/6QCSnySV. I discovered something pretty insane - buried among them, for some reason, is a 1.82TB partition that corresponds to the size of my lost data. I'm guessing that file system contains my data, but if so, what are all of the other filesystems, and why are they also so large? The Ext filesystem listed is as much as 500GB, and a few other NTFS ones are over 400GB. Where are all these coming from and what are they?

Comment: I explained earlier about all the other partitions showing up. This is good. The primary partition always starts at sector 63 and that is right. That's the one you should work on.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turned out that was a false positive of some sort. Attempting to recover from that source showed nothing there, and it actually resembled a barebones image of my main data drive than the external drive I lost, but that couldn't have been the case cause my main drive isn't 1.8TB. Something is seriously wrong, and I'm honestly not sure which way to go atm. I'll probably keep looking for a partition table with TestDisk and/or Partition Wizard - and if that fails, trying to work with the next biggest file system sector, which is 900GB.

Comment: The comments are getting out of hand here. I have stated several times now, you are not missing a partition and you are not going to recover data by "restoring" a partition. You have also overwritten the file table - I'm absolutely positive. Your ONLY hope is to stop searching for file tables and partitions and start scanning the raw drive for the bits of scraps left over. I'm not familiar with GDB and I don't usually recuva in this scenario. I use File Scavenger which does this job excellently. A significant portion of data is gone, sorry to tell you.

Comment: I'm not sure what planet you live on, but I gave you a thorough and well thought out answer in my original response. I'm not the one who accidentally formatted my hard drive. Now you refuse to accept the data is gone or very difficult to retrieve. I've given you the options you have and have been sure about them from the beginning. I even told you the tool to use and what kind of scan you have to do. I've done far more difficult data recoveries hundreds of times. Good luck with your data.

Comment: @Hashim Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice). Your comments to somebody who is only trying to help you are abusive. They have been removed.

Comment: So you removed my comments but kept all the comments from him responding to them? He wasn't "only trying to help me", he was giving conflicting information - as the comments you deleted clearly demonstrated - and then had the gall to get annoyed by my posting comments trying to make sense of them. Your deleting all of my comments and leaving his up in response to them is a clear indication of the bias you've demonstrated here.